# Let V-card QR-code auto fill in html form

Tags: javascript, php, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I have made a little registration web application for the visitors in our company. Every time a person comes in he or she has to register him- or herself by putting in all of their data and details into the registration application.

However a lot of people nowadays have a business card with a V-card QR-code on it.

When i scan that V-card with a 2D scanner this is what inside almost every V-card

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Lou Bega
FN:Bega Lou
ORG:Number five
TITLE:Voice trainer
TEL;CELL:+32 45+32 455 32 36 98
ADR;WORK:;;Abclaan 345;Roeselare;;8800;Belgium
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:lou@bega.be
URL:www.loubega.be
END:VCARD
```

I am able to filter the unwanted data by PHP

i.e.

```
using preg_match(); funtion
```

But is it possible if they scan the V-card in the first input field it filters all of the unwanted data and fills in the input fields so the visitor can check if everything is present? Perhaps with some Javascript?

```
N: equals input field name="visitorname"
ORG: equals input field name="visitorcompany"
TELL or CELL: equals input field name="visitornumber"
and so on ...
```